# How to find the components of matrix on GAP with given conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gap

Let be given the matrix
$$ A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -u & -p \\
-b & v & -q \\
-c & -w & r \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Find all possible positive integers $a,u,p,b,v,q,c,w,r$ such that

$$24>a>b,c>0,$$

$$13>v>u,w>0 ,$$

$$16>r>p,q>0 $$

and such that the determinant of matrix is divisible by 25.

I started on this way but since begining

```
gap> for a in $[b+1..23]$ do

> for $b$ in $[0..a-1]$ do

> for $c$ in $[0.. a-1]$ do

> for $r$ in $[p+1..15]$ do

> for $p$ in $[0..r-1]$ do

> for $q$ in $[0..r-1]$ do
.
.
> mt:$=[[a,-u,-p],[-b,v,-q],[-c,-w,r]]$;
```

got Error, Variable: '$b$' must have an assigned value in.

Answer (score 2):

First, a few remarks: what family do your variables belong to? Are they integers, rational numbers, etc? For now I'll assume they are integers.

This is more of a programming problem than a mathematical problem, but here goes. There are a few problems with your code:

```
for a in [b+1..23] do
    for b in [0..a−1] do
        for c in [0..c−1] do
```

1. In the first line, you define `a` as a variable taking on values between `b+1` and `23`, but you haven't defined `b` yet: you do that the very next line. So of course GAP will complain that `b` is not defined yet.
2. In the same piece of code, you also have a circular reasoning: the possible values of `a` depend on the value of `b`, but the possible values of `b` depend on the value of `a`.
3. `c` will lie in the interval `[0..c-1]`? You're again trying to define a variable using a variable that is not yet defined, but this time they are the same variable. This makes no sense.
4. `b` and `c` should be strictly greater than $0$ but the intervals include $0$.

Instead, you should pick one variable to be independent of the others. Ignoring what $b$ and $c$ are, you know that $24 > a > 0$. Then, for each value of $a$, determine what the possible values of $b$ and $c$ are. Your code could, for example, look like this:

```
for a in [1..23] do
    for b in [1..a-1] do
        for c in [1..a-1] do
            ...
        od;
    od;
od;
```

Comment: Thanx a lot dear sTertooy